# Adding second hard drive

Tags: fstab, uuid

I have been trying to set up a secondary hard drive to compliment my smaller SSD drive ...
I have been having trouble following the howto posted. 
Some how I can create the "mount point " mynewdrive" 
Set up with UUID, but upon reboot the drive needs to be reset

Comment: Please add which tutorial you're following and what you've done so far. Have you added your `mount` command to fstab?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

Comment: Have you created partitition(s)? And formatted those partitions? Then post these: `sudo parted -l` and `sudo blkid`.

Comment: Yes, formated , ext4 primary partion.

Comment: parted -l    - **Model: ATA ST250DM001 HD253 (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  250GB  250GB  primary  ext4


Model: ATA KINGSTON SH103S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

-Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  103GB  103GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      103GB   120GB  17.0GB  extended
 5      103GB   120GB  17.0GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)**

Comment: `/dev/sdb1: UUID="d1715aed-2cc5-4411-ab1f-583f8e57d389" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="d8746096-8645-4961-8ab4-af0e6d618fb1" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="e584e739-0dad-4b3d-8eee-17d6bf699b04" TYPE="ext4" `

Answer (score 0):

You must add the new mount to /etc/fstab, using the existing root mount as a start point ad adapt it.

Comment: here is my copy of fstab  `#/dev/sda1    /media/mynewdrive   ext4    defaults     0        2`

Comment: That's a comment, (they start with #), and are you sure your new drive is sda and not sdb?

Comment: this answer could be improved by explaining how to add it to fstab

Comment: here is the full fstab      `c@c-Z97X-Gaming-5:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See 
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=d1715aed-2cc5-4411-ab1f-583f8e57d389 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=d8746096-8645-4961-8ab4-af0e6d618fb1 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/sda1    /media/mynewdrive   ext4    defaults     0        2
`

Comment: yes positive it is sda @ubfan1